# Scrapy patterns for large number of requests

Tags: scrapy

I need to scrape the large site there is about ten categories and thousands (I don't really know how much) of articles in each category. The simplest approach would be to create a spider for each category and `yield` responses with every next article link for further extraction.

What I'm thinking of is to make a Top Level spiders which would extract article urls from categories to a queue. The Second Level (article) spiders then should receive each a constant number of urls (say 100) from the queue, and when a spider is finished another one is started. In this way a) we can control a number of spiders, which is a constant, say 20 b) we have an option of counting the number of articles in advance  c) spider has limited memory usage. The similar worked fine in a previous project.

Does this make sense or you can just fire as many requests from one spider as possible and it will work fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could fire as many requests from one spider as possible.

This is because scrapy doesn't process all requests at once, they are just all queued.

You can change the number of requests to be processed on settings with [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests), which could indeed give memory usage problems if it is too high (say 100). Remember that a scrapy job sets 512mb of memory by default per job.

Comment: This removes memory problem, but I still prefer having them in batches, which can be achieved with utilizing `spider_idle` to fire the next batch